# React Native Array To Json

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

I'm implementing a function to get data from the SQLite database. The function is `getTotalSalesDetails`. Using this function I can successfully get the data to the `totalSalesDetailsList` Array. I Want to convert this array to a JSON object. Is there a way to do it?

```
const [totalSalesDetailsList, setTotalSalesDetailsList] = useState([]);

const getTotalSalesDetails = () => {
        db.transaction(txn => {
            txn.executeSql(
                `SELECT invoices.id, invoices.name, invoices.date, sales.salesID, sales.totaltax, sales.totalpriceNotax, sales.totalPrice, items.itemName, items.price, items.itemId, stransaction.quantity, stransaction.tid 
                FROM stransaction
                INNER JOIN invoices ON stransaction.fk_invoice_id = invoices.id
                INNER JOIN sales ON stransaction.fk_sales_id = sales.salesID
                INNER JOIN items ON stransaction.fk_item_id = items.itemId
                WHERE stransaction.fk_invoice_id = ?`,
                [lastInvoiceDetails2],
                (sqlTxn, res) => {
                    let len = res.rows.length;

                    if (len > 0) {
                        let results = [];
                        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            let item = res.rows.item(i);
                            results.push({ id: item.id, name: item.name, date: item.date, salesID: item.salesID, totaltax: item.totaltax, totalpriceNotax: item.totalpriceNotax, totalPrice: item.totalPrice, itemName: item.itemName, price: item.price, itemId: item.itemId, quantity: item.quantity });
                        }
                        setTotalSalesDetailsList(results);
                       
                    }
                },
                error => {
                },
            );
        });
    };
```

I want to convert the Arry to JSON object the format should be like this

```
"CompanyCode" : "XXX",
  "InvoiceNumber": "123",
  "CustomerName": "Name",
  "Date": "2022-01-08",
  "TotalTax" : 200,
  "TotalPrice" : 100,
  "Items": [
    {
      "IteamName": "Cotten",
      "IteamQut": 2,
      "UnitPrice": 10,
    },
    {
      "IteamName": "Textile",
      "IteamQut": 2,
      "UnitPrice": 10,
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JSON.stringify(arr);` . for more info see [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/convert+array+to+json)